# Dropwizard Schedule Jobs with Sundial can't access session

Tags: hibernate, scheduled-tasks, dropwizard

I am trying to use dropwizard-sundial to schedule jobs. In my scheduled job, I need to access my DAOs. Whenever my scheduled job runs I receive the following error ..

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context
```

I am trying to use the method described at this link, https://github.com/timmolter/XDropWizard under the section **Inject Global Objects or Config Parameters into a Job**

This is my Application code:

```
public class ServiceApplication extends Application<OnboardingServiceConfiguration> {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OnboardingServiceApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new OnboardingServiceApplication().run(args);
    }

    private final HibernateBundle<OnboardingServiceConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<OnboardingServiceConfiguration>(com.rm.models.Application.class, EmailQueue.class) {
        @Override
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(OnboardingServiceConfiguration configuration) {
            return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "onboarding";
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<OnboardingServiceConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        // add scheduled jobs
        bootstrap.addBundle(new SundialBundle<OnboardingServiceConfiguration>(){
            @Override
            public SundialConfiguration getSundialConfiguration(OnboardingServiceConfiguration configuration) {
                return configuration.getSundialConfiguration();
            }
        });
        //  to the database
        bootstrap.addBundle(hibernate);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(OnboardingServiceConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        // add health checks
        final HealthCheckResource resource = new HealthCheckResource(
                environment.healthChecks()
        );
        environment.jersey().register(resource);

        // configure DAOs for database management
        final ApplicationDAO applicationDAO = new ApplicationDAO(hibernate.getSessionFactory());
        final EmailDAO emailDAO = new EmailDAO(hibernate.getSessionFactory());


        logger.info("Package set for scheduled jobs: " + configuration.getSundialConfiguration().getAnnotatedJobsPackageName());
        environment.getApplicationContext().setAttribute("EmailDAO", emailDAO);
        environment.getApplicationContext().setAttribute("ApplicationDAO", applicationDAO);

        // add resources for REST API endpoints
        environment.jersey().register(new ApplicationResource());

        // setup environment to run scheduled jobs
        // more info and tutorial found at https://github.com/timmolter/dropwizard-sundial
        environment.admin().addTask(new LockSundialSchedulerTask());
        environment.admin().addTask(new UnlockSundialSchedulerTask());
        environment.admin().addTask(new RemoveJobTriggerTask());
        environment.admin().addTask(new AddCronJobTriggerTask());
        environment.admin().addTask(new StartJobTask());
        environment.admin().addTask(new StopJobTask());
        environment.admin().addTask(new RemoveJobTask());
        environment.admin().addTask(new AddJobTask());
    }


}
```

And this is my Scheduled Job :

```
    @Override
public void doRun() throws JobInterruptException {
    this.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailJobs.class);

    logger.info("Running Scheduled Tasks:");

    this.emailerService = new EmailerService((EmailDAO) SundialJobScheduler.getServletContext().getAttribute("EmailDAO"));
    this.applicationDAO = (ApplicationDAO) SundialJobScheduler.getServletContext().getAttribute("ApplicationDAO");

    List<Application> applications = applicationDAO.getAllForManagerIncompleteReminder();
}
```

I am getting the DAOs, they are not null, but they are not bound to any session.  How do I fix this??

(PS, the hibernate session is working fine when I access it via the resource, just not the scheduled task)

Comment: PPS - I tried using the @UnitOfWork annotation but that didn't help.

Comment: You can get a hyper-link to given heading in GitHub by hovering the mouse at the left of the heading. Example: https://github.com/timmolter/XDropWizard#inject-global-objects-or-config-parameters-into-a-job

Comment: About `@UnitOfWork`: in your scheduler method you are outside `Jersey`-scope. Have you done the following: http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.5/docs/manual/hibernate.html#transactional-resource-methods-outside-jersey-resources ?

Comment: Hello @user1795370, Were you able to find a solution for this ?

Comment: @user1795370 were you able to find a solution for this? I am facing the sam eissue

Answer (score 0):

In your ServiceApplication instantiate your emailerService as follows and add it to the servletContext.

```
// configure DAOs for database management
    final ApplicationDAO applicationDAO = new ApplicationDAO(hibernate.getSessionFactory());
    final EmailDAO emailDAO = new EmailDAO(hibernate.getSessionFactory());


    Class[] constructorParams = {EmailDAO.class};
    Object[] objectsParam = {emailDAO};
    EmailerService emailerService = new UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory(hibernate)
                .create(EmailerService.class, constructorParams, objectsParam);
    environment.getApplicationContext().setAttribute("EMAIL_SERVICE", emailerService);
```